# Invariance of Radon-Nikodym Derivative

Tags: measure-theory

Let $\left( X, \mathcal{A} \right)$ be a measurable space, $\phi : X \to X$ a measurable map and $\mu, \nu$ two $\sigma$-finite $\phi$-invariant measures on $\left( X, \mathcal{A} \right)$.
Now, I want to show that if $\mu$ is absolutely continuous with respect to $\nu$, then

\begin{equation}
f = \frac{\mathrm{d} \nu}{\mathrm{d} \mu}
\end{equation}

is also $\phi$-invariant, i.e $f = f \circ \phi$.
Intuitively, this seems very obvious, but i have only managed to prove that

\begin{equation}
\int_{\phi^{-1} \left( A \right)} \left( f - f \circ \phi \right) \mathrm{d} \nu = 0
\end{equation}

for all measurable sets $A \in \mathcal{A}$.
If $\phi$ was assumed to be bijective and bi-measurable, one could replace the integration domain with $A$ which would then give the desired result by considering sublevel sets. But I strongly suspect that it is not necessary...